# ACH validation in run time

Tags: authorize.net, plaid, authorize.net-cim

I have validated the credit card in `Authorize.net` using the `authOnlyTransaction` method. I have also the option of ACH validation but there are some problems in validating that may be because of lack of knowledge in payment domain.

1. I tried to use the authorize.net but i have to specify the amount first.
2. It does not validate all the credentials but only routing number and bank name
3. I have to wait 2-3 days for the verification from the bank regarding the payment.

Question is, is there any method which i can use to validate the `ACH`
 on my webpage when user hit the verify button ? I have also tried to use the `plaid` but in the documentation it states that this also required some days to valid. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get real time verification of a bank account through Authorize.Net. ACH works differently than credit cards and this is one of the limitations of it (the upside being lower cost associated with accepting ACH payments).

[Plaid](https://plaid.com/) does offer account verification through an API which returns an immediate result. [Plaid is not free](https://plaid.com/pricing/), however.

If you provide a service or product and accept ACH payments, and don't want the risk associated waiting from verification that the account is valid or pay fees, then you should postpone allowing access to that service or shipping your good until payment clears. Otherwise, a service like Plaid is what you are looking for.

Comment: thankyou for your help. I have some basic understanding questions. For the ACH verification i have to use the `plaid`? And still it will take 2-3 days to verify the credentials?. Second thing is plaid give a free testing account to check it or not like auth.net ?

Comment: You don't *have* to use Plaid. It just makes the process of verifying an ACH account easier but it certainly isn't required. You could just wait for the payment to clear to verify the account is good. But after speaking to a development team here at work who use Plaid in their application, I can confirm account validation is *immediate*. No waiting. And it does look like [Plaid offers developer accounts](https://support.plaid.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2526322-development-mode-account).

Comment: SO for validation i can rely on plaid? Actually for the time being the requirement is only the validation not the actual payment.

Comment: Yes, you can. We use it in a high volume application used by Fortune 500 companies without issue.

Comment: but i think plaid did not provide the documentation for the `PHP`

Comment: They may not have an SDK for PHP (I haven't looked) but APIs are language agnostic. So their API documentation should tell you everything you need to connect to it and receive a response.

Comment: Thank you for your response for helping so far!

Comment: i came across a question in this regard that what type of validation plaid provides. Like only bank name and routing number or the account name and Account number validation is also being provided by plaid?

Comment: [Their website](https://plaid.com/products/auth/) explains what they can do

Comment: i have read but they have not specified the details about the authentication they have provided.